# Firebase database can't get uid

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I made a project about the chat application. the application runs normally, but sometimes the database in firebase crashes while uploading. the error is that the uid in firebase auth is not retrieved.

```
private fun uploadImageFirebase() {
    if (selected == null){
        saveUsertoFirebase("")
    } else {
        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/image/$filename")

        ref.putFile(selected!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("Sign", "Img ok : ${it.metadata?.path}")

                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("sign", "file location $it")

                    saveUsertoFirebase(it.toString())
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("fail", "Failed to upload ${it.message}")
            }
    }
}

private fun saveUsertoFirebase(profileImage: String) {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
    val user = UserModel(uid, edtName.text.toString(), profileImage, edtNomor.text.toString())

    ref.setValue(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("Sign", "account saved")

            val intent = Intent(this, Log_in::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("fail", "Failed save ${it.message}")
        }
}
```

[image]

database should be

[image]

How come ?

Comment: " the error is that the uid in firebase auth is not retrieved." Please edit your question to include (copy/paste) the exact error message, and stack trace that you find in your logcat output.

Comment: You should use FirebaseUser instance instead of Auth and get uid by user.getuid() or user.uid(). Try this and let me know if it do not work.